# Add additional regressor for phi and change link function for phi in GAM beta regression

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I would like to use GAM to run penalized beta regression. Because of my setting, I also need to change the regression of precision, phi.

Here is my test code:

```
y <- c(0.0000943615,0.0074918919,0.0157332851,0.0783308615,
       0.1546375803,0.5558444681,0.8583806898,0.9617216854,
       0.9848004112,0.9964662546)
x <- log(c(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.6, 3.2, 4.5, 6.4))
fit.gam <- gam(y~x,family=betar(link="logit"))
```

I noticed that there is another argument `theta` in `betar`, but I don't know how to set it. Seems like `theta` requires me to enter a number.

The default link function for phi in GAM beta regression is log link. My questions are how to change the link function to be identity and how to add `x` as a regressor for `phi`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't possible.  I can show you how to fit the particular model you've got here with the `bbmle` package, but `bbmle` can't do penalized regression, or at least not the fancy kinds of penalized regression that `mgcv` does. I'm not aware offhand of an R package that can do this (penalized regression plus covariate-dependent, identity-link estimation of the dispersion).  Can you change your example so that it is realistic in terms of the kind of penalized term you want to use for the fixed effects?

Comment: The theta parameter is only used to fix phi, rather than solve for it in the regression.  I agree with @Ben Bolker that what you want is not possible with mgcv.  You certainly can't do a beta regression with an identity link because the (0,1) constraints wont be respected.

Comment: I think the OP wants to estimate the dispersion parameter on the identity scale, not the location parameter - although there's still a potential problem because the identity link won't constrain the dispersion to be positive ...